# Icon not showing on mobile

Tags: android, css, icons

I'm building a website in WordPress and have bought the following theme: http://my.studiopress.com/themes/sixteen-nine/#demo-full .

This is currently my site
http://jiri.tourdog.nl/

When viewed on a mobile device, one is supposed to see a menu icon that one can click on to reveal a drop-down. When I visit the original theme-demo on my mobile device the icon shows like it's supposed to. However, when I check my own site I can't see the icon (although the part is press-able and shows the drop-down). On my laptop I can resize my screen and it'll also show.

So this leads me to believe this is not a WordPress issue nor is it an issue inside the theme (the css is exactly the same as the demo).

What could it be?

Summary: Icon doesn't show on my mobile device, does show on desktop, and am also able to see the original theme demo's icon on my mobile device.

Comment: This sounds like you need to contact the developer of that theme first.

Comment: font: normal 24px/1 'dashicons'; this font is probably causing an error [DASHICONS], which version of WordPress you are using, because dash icon font became avaliable after 3.8, I found it online